# Hide parts of the post content on the home page

Tags: posts, content, homepage

I have a post that contains a video (or a slider) and some text.

Is it possible to hide the text on the home page, but still display the rest? How would I do that?

Comment: Well, this can either be done by PHP and/or CSS and/or jQuery, so there is not **the** solution. If you could include the code of your `home.php` file we could provide you with a fitting solution. Also, do you want to have this for one single post, are there more, or should this effect every post that is displayed on your home page?

Answer (score 1):

If your video is pasted into the post body, you have a couple of options.

1. Use a filter on `the_content` and `preg_replace` to remove the content.
2. Wrap your content in a shortcode.

I am going to recommend option #2 because option #1 involves processing markup with regex which is tricky and prone to error, and your question does not contain enough information for me to be able to write that anyway.

```
function hide_on_home_page_wpse_97587($atts,$content) {
  if (!is_home()) {
    return $content;
  }
}
add_shortcode('nohome','hide_on_home_page_wpse_97587');
```

Then when you post content put the switched content between `[nohome]` and `[/nohome]`