# Hide parts of the post content after typing it's name or searching it by category

Tags: posts, categories, search, content

[Code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97587/hide-parts-of-the-post-content-on-the-home-page) "nohome" worked for displaying 
wanted (hided'n'waiting) content 
on home page (just postname and image)

How it could be adjusted or
modified to make the same after
name of post has been typed in
searchbox or searched by Categories?
(At the moment the result of that 2 actions is simply = display whole founded posts)

Sincerely 
Jacob

Comment: That is my code you are talking about but I don't understand the question. You want to also hide content on search pages and category archives?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply the same logic to the category archives and the search results as in that question you reference, the following should do it.

```
// modified code from http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/97589/21376
function hide_on_home_page_wpse_97587($atts,$content) {
  if (!is_home()
      && !is_category()
      && !is_search()
  ) {
    return $content;
  }
}
add_shortcode('nohome','hide_on_home_page_wpse_97587');
```